# HTTP status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, http, servlets, web.xml

I am getting this "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" error when I run my project. The funny thing is, it was running perfectly fine two days ago. After I made a few changes to my code but then restored my original code and its giving me this error. Could you please help me?

Here is my index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="login.do">
<div>
<table>
            <tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="e_name"/>
            </td>  </tr>
            <tr><td> Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="e_pass"/>
            </td>  </tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name ="e_submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Here is my Login servlet:

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /*
         * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
         */
        int status;
        String submit = request.getParameter("e_submit");
        String submit2 = request.getParameter("a_submit");
        out.println("Here1");
        String e_name = request.getParameter("e_name");
        String e_password = request.getParameter("e_pass");
        String a_name = request.getParameter("a_name");
        String a_password = request.getParameter("a_pass");
        out.println(e_name+e_password+a_name+a_password);
        Author author = new Author(a_name,a_password);  
        Editor editor = new Editor(e_name,e_password);

      // If it is an AUTHOR login:

       if(submit==null){
       status = author.login(author);
       out.println("Author Login");
       //Incorrect login details
       if(status==0) {
           out.println("Incorrect");

       RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index_F.html");
       view.forward(request, response);

       }
       //Correct login details --- AUTHOR

       else {

              out.println("Correct login details");
              HttpSession session = request.getSession();    
              session.setAttribute(a_name, "a_name");

              RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index_S.jsp"); 
              view.forward(request, response);
            }

       }

       //If it is an EDITOR login

       else if (submit2==null){

           status = editor.login(editor);

           //Incorrect login details

           if(status==0) {

       RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index_F.html");
       view.forward(request, response);
            }

           //Correct login details --- EDITOR

           else {
               out.println("correct");
               HttpSession session = request.getSession();    
       session.setAttribute(e_name, "e_name");
       session.setAttribute(e_password, "e_pass");
               RequestDispatcher view   = request.getRequestDispatcher("index_S_1.html"); 
               view.forward(request, response);

            }           }


        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");



    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doPost(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doGet(req, resp);
}}
```

And my web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/login.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I use Glassfish v3 server - let me know anything else you need to know

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: [See this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4297049/235710)

Comment: I wonder why it was running perfectly fine 2 days ago !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is there a `processRequest` method in your code? Who will call that method?

You can't get up to that method by calling `super.doGet()` or `super.doPost()`
you need to call that method explicitly.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req,resp)
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req,resp)
}
```

**EDIT**

Do this

```
response.sendRedirect("index_F.html");
return;
```

instead of

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index_F.html");
view.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because on your `doGet()` and `doPost()` method, you're calling it's `super` methods. Rather, call the `processRequest()` inside the respective methods mentioned above.

The `super.doGet()` and `super.doPost()` method, returns an HTTP 405, by default, so you don't call your superclass `doGet()` and `doPost()`.

Comment: I'm looking for the same question from hours and non of the answer worked for me. You answer helped me to sort it out. I'm surprised that everybody have overlooked this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `doPost()` you have to call `processRequest()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `doGet()` and `doPost()` method without actually implementing (using `super`).

The HttpServlet basically follows the template method pattern where all non-overridden HTTP methods returns a `HTTP 405` error "Method not supported". When you override such a method, you should not call `super` method, because you would otherwise still get the `HTTP 405` error. The same story goes on for your doPost() method.

Call the `processRequest(req,resp)` inside the respective methods mentioned above.

EDIT:

Second,

Do not use dispatcher to forward request to HTML. Use redirect anyway if you want to show html only.

```
response.sendRedirect("index_F.html");
return;
```

Also, It is good practice to use `redirect` when you do Logout or send back for invalid credentials.

Comment: I did that. The error was eliminated, thanks a million! But however my page wont get forwarded [ I have used RequestDispatcher to forward to another page]

Comment: Did that, it still won't forward the page for me

Comment: @WontSay: What is happening actually ? "it still won't forward the page" will not help.

Comment: in the servlet code, i wrote some html code (this was earlier to chk whether i receive the values from the html page). This html code gets displayed. What should happen is - the code shouldn't be displayed, it should display (i.e. forward) the html file specified in `redirect`